# `ng-pattern` - how to check for only numbers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I am using an `ng-pattern` to check for ONLY numbers in my input. But for me that's not working. I can able to type in `characters` after the `number`. How can I restrict that?

here is my code :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/KGd8K/1804/)

Comment: For accepting only number in your text box i think better you can use type="number" in your input tag.

Comment: u may refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827570/validate-natural-input-number-with-ngpattern

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use this expression

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
```

UPDATE :

for accepting the only characters,you can use like this.

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
```

Comment: Ok. for accepting charactors can i use `ng-pattern="/^[a-z][A-Z]*$/"`- ?

Comment: What is the exact requirement?

Comment: only need to allow characters ( name field )

Comment: it didn't work for angularjs 1.2.x, it also allows characters

Answer (score 7):

Try this regex:  It should work `/^[0-9]+$/` 
+ sign is for accepting one or more digits.

Answer (score 5):

`ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"` //change to

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{1,10}$/"
```

NOTE: '\d' can check not only 0-9, also for many digits like greek digits

Comment: why do want to change it? what is the benefit in this approach?

Answer (score 1):

For reactive form

```
this.form = fb.group({

  number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]]

})
```