# How to define a pattern of a string as PAN number in angularjs.

Tags: html, eclipse

```
    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><spring:message code="label.entity.PANNumber"></spring:message></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" 
                                            name="<spring:message code="label.PANNumber"></spring:message>" id="PANNumber"
                                            data-ng-model="manageCustomerObj.panNumber"  maxlength="10" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

what should i have to add for allowing to PAN number in this(ABCDE1234F) format only ?
i am using eclipse.

Comment: try it  `name="<spring:message code='label.PANNumber'></spring:message>"`

Comment: its also not working.

Comment: i want to save my page with either pin_no is in correct format(AAAAA1111A) or empty...if we enter the incorrect format than it would show error msg “enter right pin”.

Answer (score 0):

first convert the string to uppercase and then check with following regex pattern

```
^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$
```

[See this Example to use regex with ng-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827570/validate-natural-input-number-with-ngpattern)

**EDIT:**
For case insensitive search use `^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]$`

[See Demo For Case Insesitive search](http://jsfiddle.net/vvw732nL/2/)

[See Demo For Case sesitive search](http://jsfiddle.net/vvw732nL/1/)

Comment: i added only ng-pattern="^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$" after maxlength="10".....its not working.

Comment: on keyup event call a function where you verify this regex pattern and if it does not match show the error or if you want to use ng-pattern see this answer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827570/validate-natural-input-number-with-ngpattern`

Comment: there is no keyup event.

Comment: use `ng-change="myFunc()"`

Comment: i want to save my page with either pin_no is in correct format(AAAAA1111A) or empty...if we enter the incorrect format than it would show error msg “enter right pin”.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/"
```

edit:
added `{1}` to last, now check and let me know

Comment: what error occured??and how you'r trying? will you plz post your code with keyup event also until what you tried now?

Comment: it takes albhabets/numbers/special character everything.......i did only that i added yr code after  maxlength="10" in my code. and alphabets are in small letters

Comment: if want only upper letters in your pan than you can use this `ng-pattern="/^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$/"`

Comment: its also not working it shows also in small letters and not in specified pattern

Comment: plz post your all code with respect to pan validation

Comment: i want to save my page with either pin_no is in correct format(AAAAA1111A) or empty...if we enter the incorrect format than it would show error msg “enter right pin”.

Comment: yeah but post your all code related to PAN validation.

Comment: $scope.validatePanNo = function(PAN){
            if(PAN!="")
            {
            if($scope.manageCustomerObj.panNumber!= /(^([a-zA-Z]{5})([0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z]{1})$)/)
               {
                        logger.logError("Please enter PAN in format only !!");
                        
                    }
                    };
            }